# Using NodeJs/Express for Rest API - Using Java console app

Tags: java, node.js, rest, express

I have a java console application, that prints out strings of information, using 3 or 4 methods to do so. e.g. listValues(), listValuesAsc()

Is it possible to create a NodeJS/Express server that can call my Java App and use the outputs from the methods as responses within the web-server

Comment: What is the java command you wish to print the output to your express app?

Comment: At the moment I just have a simple Java app that has a main() which would do something like person.listAge(). Is it possible to have a Node/Express web-server link and call person.listAge() instead of the java main method? Not sure if this is even possible

Comment: The only solution I know would be to use the spawn function of nodeJS to execute a command (you would execute a java command and then return the result with express). You should look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817897/execute-java-code-on-a-server